# breaking json for stacked highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am passing a Json to highcharts

json:  `{"0":[{"name":"normal","data":["1647","270905","412080","13609","17062","20889","16","765097","13424","14","2044","630686","104019","3097","733","1462"]},{"name":"rft","data":[1300177,4599692,957739,4177103,3436151,3752121,1978772,1850918,2538336,521542,2951953,4108915,1516107,3329831,661657,3447965]}]}`

and used this code to breakdown and passing to highcharts:

```
series: [{
    data: (function() {
      var chart_data =[];
      $.each(obj[0], function (index, value) {
          var arra=[];
         // alert(value['name'])
          arra['name']=value['name'];
          arra['data']=[];
          //alert(value['data'].length);
          $.each(value['data'],function(ind,val){
            arra['data'].push(parseInt(val));
          });
          //console.log(arra);
          chart_data.push(arra);
          });
      return chart_data ;
  })()
}]
```

but not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var arra=[];
     // alert(value['name'])
     arra['name']=value['name'];
```

This code shows you are treating an array (only number indices) as an object (string index).  Try using:

```
     var arra={};
     // alert(value['name'])
     arra['name']=value['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your clue....

After that I changed my code....

data: (function() {
var chart_data =[];
$.each(obj[0], function (index, value) {
 var arra={};
 var new_str=[];
 arra.name=value['name'];
 $.each(value['data'],function(ind,val){
   new_str.push(parseInt(val));
 });
 arra.data=new_str;
 chart_data.push(arra);
});
                                        console.log(JSON.stringify(chart_data));
return JSON.stringify(chart_data);
})()

when I am checking console.. I am getting exact data that I want, but chart is not building till now...

any other suggestions......

Comment: What do you mean by "the chart is not building until now"?

Comment: What does running it with those logging statements throw up?

Comment: [{"name":"normal","data":[1647,270905,412080,13609,17062,20889,16,765097,13424,14,2044,630686,104019,3097,733,1462]},{"name":"rft","data":[4359537,965216,2388950,4986841,2349173,191815,2919504,4323499,2626114,3734625,3517050,1162304,137234,4703022,2803464,2087634]}]

Comment: So isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is required by highcharts. its not working when I am returning this through code but when I pasting this logging statement as a data element its working....

Answer (score 0):

First construct your JSON Data to exclude the keys "0" and "1" if that will be possible. Once done you can  plot your graph as can be seen on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/09m5zpa0/)

```
var obj=[{"name":"normal","data":["1647","270905","412080","13609","17062","20889","16","765097","13424","14","2044","630686","104019","3097","733","1462"]},{"name":"rft","data":[1300177,4599692,957739,4177103,3436151,3752121,1978772,1850918,2538336,521542,2951953,4108915,1516107,3329831,661657,3447965]}];
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        series: (function(){
            return obj;
        })()
    });
});
```

But if your JSON Data must be as it is currently, then you can change series to:

```
        series: (function(){
            return obj[0];
        })()
```

Comment: Why `function(){return obj[0];})()`?  Just use `series: obj[0]`.